# Error fetching OAuth credentials: "invalid_client" with symfony 4

Tags: oauth-2.0, symfony4

I had a probleme recently with Google Oauth , i did't change any think but i had this probleme : Error fetching OAuth credentials: "invalid_client".

Here is my configuration on file `.env`:

```
'BRANDS_REPO_OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID' => '378646254450k9rb76sap5eqvsk2id8qg50gv74ocat8.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'BRANDS_REPO_OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET' => 'xxxxxxx',
```

Any updates or any ideas how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
Error 401: invalid_client
The OAuth client was not found.
```

=> used client `378646254450k9rb76sap5eqvsk2id8qg50gv74ocat8.apps.googleusercontent.com` doesn't exists anymore (probably someone has deleted it). Contact your admin and ask to create new one or create own Google OAuth client.